# How to stay connected to HikVision ANPR Camera stream of events?

Tags: python, rtsp, hikvision

I am trying to connect to an hik vision camera installed at a car park to monitor entries and exists. To get the event data,  I am using [hikvisionapi][1].

Here is what I am doing to connect to the camera:

```
from hikvisionapi import AsyncClient

cam = AsyncClient('http://XXX.XX.XXX.X:XXXX', 'xxxxx', 'XXXXXX')

async for event in cam.Event.notification.alertStream(method='get', type='stream', timeout=None):
    if(event['EventNotificationAlert']['eventType'] == 'ANPR'):
        print(event['EventNotificationAlert'])
```

With this, I am able to get event data, however after the first 'ANPR' event is detected, I get an 'IndexError'. I have tried other ways like:

```
from hikvisionapi import AsyncClient
import logging
import time

cam = AsyncClient('http://XXX.XX.XXX.X:XXXX', 'xxxxx', 'XXXXXX')

while True:
    try:
        async for event in cam.Event.notification.alertStream(method='get', type='stream', timeout=None):
            if event['EventNotificationAlert']['eventType'] == 'ANPR':
                logging.info(event['EventNotificationAlert'])
        time.sleep(1) # Add a delay to avoid overloading the system
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

and I also tried :

```
from hikvisionapi import AsyncClient

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cam = AsyncClient('http://XXX.XX.XXX.X:XXXX', 'xxxxxxx', 'XXXXX')
    while True:
        async for event in cam.Event.notification.alertStream(method='get', type='stream', timeout=None):
            if 'EventNotificationAlert' in event and 'eventType' in event['EventNotificationAlert']:
                if event['EventNotificationAlert']['eventType'] == 'ANPR':
                    logging.info(event['EventNotificationAlert']['ANPR'])
                else:
                    logging.info(event['EventNotificationAlert'])
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('No events')
                time.sleep(1)
```

All the the other way that use a infinite while loop, I get the first ANPR event but then it doesn't detect any more events.. The code doesn't crash , it keeps running but no more events are detected.

I will appreciate any help.

So my question is, how do I stay connected to the stream and ignore any errors.
[1]: https://pypi.org/project/hikvisionapi/

Comment: please check the python code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77843753/11816440

Comment: sorry, the same post

Answer (score 0):

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import csv
import os

class ANPRRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        # Read the body of the request
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)

        # Split the payload into parts
        parts = post_data.split(b'--boundary\r\n')[1:-1]  # Exclude the first and last split elements

        for part in parts:
            headers, body = part.split(b'\r\n\r\n', 1)
            body = body.strip()

            # Process XML part
            if b'anpr.xml' in headers:
                self.process_xml(body)

            # Process image part
            elif b'.jpg' in headers:
                filename = re.findall(rb'filename="([^"]+)"', headers)[0].decode()
                self.save_image(body, filename)

        # Send response
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Received and processed ANPR event".encode('utf-8'))
    def append_to_csv(self, license_plate):
        # CSV file path
        csv_file = 'license_plates.csv'

        # Check if the CSV file exists
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(csv_file)

        # Open the file in append mode
        with open(csv_file, mode='a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)

            # If the file does not exist, write the header
            if not file_exists:
                writer.writerow(['License Plate'])

            # Write the license plate data
            writer.writerow([license_plate])

    def process_xml(self, xml_data):
        # Parse XML data
        #print(xml_data)
        try:
            
            root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
            
            # Find the license plate element
            # Update XPath to include namespace prefix
            namespaces = {'ns': 'http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema'}

                # Find the license plate element
            # Update XPath to include namespace prefix
            license_plate_element = root.find('.//ns:ANPR/ns:licensePlate', namespaces)
    
            if license_plate_element is not None and license_plate_element.text:
                license_plate = license_plate_element.text.strip()
                print(f"License Plate: {license_plate}")
                self.append_to_csv(license_plate)
            else:
                print("License plate not found in XML.")
        except ET.ParseError as e:
            print(f"Error parsing XML: {e}")


    def save_image(self, image_data, image_name):
        # Save the image
        with open(image_name, 'wb') as image_file:
            image_file.write(image_data)
        print(f"Saved image {image_name}")

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=ANPRRequestHandler, port=8888):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print(f"Starting httpd on port {port}...")
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

and this is the wireshark data:
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary
Host: 10.199.13.29:8888
Connection: close
Content-Length: 525605

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anpr.xml"; filename="anpr.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 2744

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress>10.199.27.128</ipAddress>
<portNo>8888</portNo>
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<macAddress>d4:e8:53:bc:4c:02</macAddress>
<channelID>1</channelID>
<dateTime>2024-01-19T11:17:19+08:00</dateTime>
<activePostCount>1</activePostCount>
<eventType>ANPR</eventType>
<eventState>active</eventState>
<eventDescription>ANPR</eventDescription>
<channelName>Camera 01</channelName>
<ANPR>
<country>3</country>
<licensePlate>PECT600</licensePlate>
<line>2</line>
<direction>reverse</direction>
<confidenceLevel>97</confidenceLevel>
<plateType>unknown</plateType>
<plateColor>unknown</plateColor>
<licenseBright>0</licenseBright>
<dangmark>no</dangmark>
<twoWheelVehicle>no</twoWheelVehicle>
<threeWheelVehicle>no</threeWheelVehicle>
<plateCharBelieve>99,99,99,99,99,99,99</plateCharBelieve>
<vehicleType>vehicle</vehicleType>
<detectDir>8</detectDir>
<detectType>0</detectType>
<alarmDataType>0</alarmDataType>
<vehicleInfo>
<index>8050</index>
<colorDepth>2</colorDepth>
<color>white</color>
<length>0</length>
<vehicleLogoRecog>1036</vehicleLogoRecog>
<vehileSubLogoRecog>0</vehileSubLogoRecog>
<vehileModel>0</vehileModel>
</vehicleInfo>
<pictureInfoList>
<pictureInfo>
<fileName>licensePlatePicture.jpg</fileName>
<type>licensePlatePicture</type>
<dataType>0</dataType>
<picRecogMode>1</picRecogMode>
<absTime>20240119111719654</absTime>
<pId>2024011911172148100XqTdZBLMwoCkk</pId>
</pictureInfo>
<pictureInfo>
<fileName>detectionPicture.jpg</fileName>
<type>detectionPicture</type>
<dataType>0</dataType>
<picRecogMode>1</picRecogMode>
<absTime>20240119111719654</absTime>
<plateRect>
<X>691</X>
<Y>397</Y>
<width>59</width>
<height>34</height>
</plateRect>
<pId>2024011911172148200AcB8K3CS9B2h5</pId>
</pictureInfo>
</pictureInfoList>
<originalLicensePlate>PECT600</originalLicensePlate>
<CRIndex>3</CRIndex>
<vehicleListName>otherList</vehicleListName>
<plateSize>0</plateSize>
</ANPR>
<UUID>2024011911172144900FlERIduqg06eKsYuvLX072NugIxaHw22mHG5D5KBmWqX</UUID>
<picNum>2</picNum>
<monitoringSiteID></monitoringSiteID>
<isDataRetransmission>false</isDataRetransmission>
<DeviceGPSInfo>
<longitudeType>E</longitudeType>
<latitudeType>N</latitudeType>
<Longitude>
<degree>111</degree>
<minute>0</minute>
<sec>0.000000</sec>
</Longitude>
<Latitude>
<degree>0</degree>
<minute>22</minute>
<sec>0.000000</sec>
</Latitude>
</DeviceGPSInfo>
<detectionBackgroundImageResolution>
<height>1568</height>
<width>2560</width>
</detectionBackgroundImageResolution>
<countryAbbreviation>NON</countryAbbreviation>
</EventNotificationAlert>

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="licensePlatePicture.jpg"; filename="2024011911172148100XqTdZBLMwoCkk.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 5940

......JFIF..
```